# Vertical multi-level accordion menu and document.getElementById("side_bar_t").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I would appreciate your help to figure out why level 3's items (Product A I-1-1, Product A I-1-2 or Product B I-1-1, Product B I-1-2) integrated to this accordion menu using an innerHTML aren't displayed.
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ng46se3s/20/

```js
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
   element.removeClass('open');
   element.find('li').removeClass('open');
   element.find('ul').slideUp();
  }
  else {
   element.addClass('open');
   element.children('ul').slideDown();
   element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
   element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
   element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
   element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
  }
 });

 $('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');

 (function getColor() {
  var r, g, b;
  var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
  textColor = textColor.slice(4);
  r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
  textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
  textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
  var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
  if (l > 0.7) {
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
   $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
  }
 })();

 function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
     r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
     var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
     var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

     if(max == min){
         h = s = 0;
     }
     else {
         var d = max - min;
         s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
         switch(max){
             case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
             case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
             case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
         }
         h /= 6;
     }
     return l;
 }
});
} )( jQuery );
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Display_level2(form) {
      i = form.select_name.selectedIndex; 
    switch(i) {
    case 0 : return; break;
    case 1 : document.getElementById("Level2").innerHTML='<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Product A I-1</span></a><ul><li><a href="#"><span>Product A I-1-1</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>Product A I-1-2</span></a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#"><span>Product A I-2</span></a></li>'; break;
     case 2 : document.getElementById("Level2").innerHTML='<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Product B I-1</span></a><ul><li><a href="#"><span>Product B I-1-1</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>Product B I-1-2</span></a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#"><span>Product B I-2</span></a></li>'; break;
    }
   }
       </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu' style="vertical-align: top;">
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Menu</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products I</span></a>
       <form><li>
       <select style="width: 200px;" id="select" name="select_name" onchange="Display_level2(this.form)">
      <option>- select -</option>
   <option>A</option>
         <option>B</option>
           </select></li>
       </form>
   <ul id="Level2"></ul>
   </li>    
<li class="has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Products II</span></a>
         <ul><li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Products II-1</span></a>
          <ul><li><a href="#"><span>Products II-1-1</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Products II-1-2</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Products II-2</span></a></li>
         </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the general look of the code and structure, your main issue here is that `body onload` is called **after** `$(document).ready` which is the one that applies the menu styles.

So you have to move your function to `$(document).ready` or move the latter to `body onload`..

I would move your function to `$(document).ready` as in this [modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/ng46se3s/3/) of your fiddle, but as you seem to really want to keep your function definition in the `<head>` section, you can at least move the call like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ng46se3s/23/)

In case you need to modify your menu options/HTML, you need to re-run the code you currently in `$(document).ready` so I would move that to separate function and call it when options are changed like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ng46se3s/29/)

Comment: Actually I would like to find a way to include that in the <head><script type="text/javascript">"In reality, there is a more detailed script around the function here and it's not called using a body onload"</script></head><body>... of my html as shown in the example. (I have simplified the example so we can focus on the encountered issue:  level 3's items not displayed when calling the function) Thanks.

Comment: I made an update, the example should be most telling now. Thanks!

Comment: If you put your code in your own .html file instead of jsfiddle, it will probably render correctly. Btw, do not edit my answer to illustrate changes, edit your question :)

Comment: The code was first tested on my own .html file and the level 3's items do not work as on jsfiddle!

Comment: Updated my answer with the bits of information you provided now.. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, yes, actually, before coming here, I have tried to load the jquery script after the function by including the the jquery script inside the body at the end: <script src="script.js"></script></body> but it didn't work.
I think you didn't paid attention, but I have updated the example as specified in my comment above (http://jsfiddle.net/ng46se3s/20/). I don't want to load the function immediately, (I use an "onchange" to call it), so I cannot include it inside the script anymore, please let me know if you have an idea on how to deal with this issue. Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: My answer still points you in the right direction: your menu rendering is only done on load. If you want to change it, just re-run the code you have on document ready like this http://jsfiddle.net/ng46se3s/29/

Comment: Done and glad that was helpful.